# onBlur and onFocus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox that is using a masking plugin for Phone and onblur I am removing a particular class. However on tab key from another field it again turns to red. The code is as follows:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Alt. Phone is not correct" data-val-regex-pattern="(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}" id="AltPhone" maxlength="14" name="AltPhone" tabindex="6" type="text" value="" class="">
```

```js
$("#AltPhone").blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
    $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
});

$("#AltPhone").focus(function () {
   $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
   $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
});
```

The `blur` function is working as expected, but `focus` is not.

Comment: Try to replace `focus` to `focusout` and check again :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code will work for you and let me know.

```
$("#AltPhone").focusout(function () {
   $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
   $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in console its working fine .Don't know but it may be because of your plugin.If possible please post some code.

```js
$("#AltPhone").blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
    $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
  console.log("blur");
});

$("#AltPhone").focus(function () {
   $("label[for='AltPhone']").removeClass('input-validation-error');
   $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
  console.log("focus");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Alt. Phone is not correct" data-val-regex-pattern="(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}" id="AltPhone" maxlength="14" name="AltPhone" tabindex="6" type="text" value="" class="">
```

Comment: And the problem is that OnBlur function is working nicely and but when I move from other field through tab key or using shift+tab then that field again turns into red

Comment: I can help you but only if you provide more code because this code is doing what it supposed to do ... other wise its all just "air hit"